Where are math expressions supported in TikZ
I searched through the user guide and was unable to find out where are math expressions supported inside the tikzpicture environment (I mean, besides coordinate calculations and let commands, that are well documented).
For example, in the following code all but the last command work fine.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0, 0) -- (1, 1);
  \draw (0, 0) -- (1, 1 + 1^2);
  \draw (0, 0) -- (1, {sin(0)});
  \draw[opacity=exp(0) - 0.9] (0, 0) -- (0, -1);
  \draw[color=red!{10+10}] (0, 0) -- (-1, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

One could say that expressions are evaluated inside coordinates, but then the opacity example shows that they are also evaluated in options, but then again the color example invalidates that supposition.

red!{10+10} isn't a valid colour specification and color requires such a specification. colours are special in various ways. it isn't where, but also/rather what.

The point is that if the expression had been evaluated, then red!20 would be a valid xcolor spec.

Colors are not part of TikZ, it uses xcolor for that. You can do color=red!\inteval{10+10} or color=red!\fpeval{10+10} (if it's not just integers). If you load my ext.misc TikZ library color/.pgfmath wrap={red!##1}{10+10} can be used.

you can use mathematical expressions where pgfmath is (or may be) invoked, but pgfmath isn't invoked inside a colour specification because pgf doesn't deal with the colours itself. (ultimately, these get passed through to the backend as they are engine-dependant, but xcolor sits between pgf and the variable implementations so the syntax is uniform, even though the actual instructions required are not.) so it isn't because it is in the options rather than in a coordinate. it's rather what that option does with any value it is given. for other options, a pgfmath expression is fine.

I can't answer your question, but maybe you can do this
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0, 0) -- (1, 1);
  \draw (0, 0) -- (1, 1 + 1^2);
  \draw (0, 0) -- (1, {sin(0)});
  \draw[opacity=exp(0) - 0.9] (0, 0) -- (0, -1);
  \pgfmathparse{10+10}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\colorvalue{10+10}
  \draw[color=red!\colorvalue] (0, 0) -- (-1, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Yes, I usually do this, then I realized that expressions were supported inside coordinates, tried in a few more places, but it's all hit and miss, and AFAICS not documented.

TikZ runs almost everything through \pgfmathparse.  The main exceptions are the optional arguments.   You can even fix that by using braces, e.g [radius={4*\r}].
